# Regular expression to get text after underscore which is used as a delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, string, text

I have a string like this:

- blah blah blah_0123

So basically i need a regular expression to get those 4 numeric values after the _ delimiter.  I'm sure it's super simply but Regex looks like a foreign language to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be this regular expression:

```
_([0-9]+)
```

(Capture group 1 holds the number.)

---

Or if your engine supports lookbehinds (which as far as I remember is not the case for C#):

```
(?<=_)[0-9]+
```

(Capture group 0 holds the number.)

---

The `(...)` denotes a catch group. In your match object you can then either access them by their index via `yourMatch.Groups[index].Value` or if you named your catch groups via `(?<name>...)` by their name like `yourMatch.Groups[name].Value`. The value will then hold whatever was matched by that particular group's sub-expression (in your case the 4-digit number).

---

Also if you only want the regex to match if those are exactly 4 numeric characters,
then replace the `+` with `{4}\b`

<sub>Edit: As Alan Moore correctly pointed out those are called "capture group", not "catch group". I need more sleep.</sub>

Comment: +1, but "catch group" is a new one on me; most people refer to them as *capturing* groups.

Comment: The `(...)` denotes a catch group. In your match object you can then either access them by their index via `yourMatch.Groups[index].Value` or if you named your catch groups via `(?<name>...)` by their name like `yourMatch.Groups[name].Value`. The value will then hold whatever was matched by that particular group's sub-expression (in your case the 4-digit number).

Comment: Correct, but the *name* "catch group" is non-standard.  You're much more likely to see them called "capturing groups".

Comment: @AlanMoore: True, thanks. Always mixing them up in my head. Will fix post. Also the comment obviously wasn't supposed to be a comment, but an edit to the answer itself. Duh. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Regex: `_(?<number>[0-9]+)`

```
var match = new Regex("_(?<number>[0-9]+)").Match("blah blah blah_0123");

if(match.Success)
{
    var value = match.Groups["number"].Value;
    var number = Int.Parse(value);

    Console.WriteLine(value);  // this will write "0123"
    Console.WriteLine(number); // this will write "123"
}
```